# Highcharts erroneously inserting numbered extra categories in error

Tags: javascript, highcharts

My co-worker and I are mystified as to why highcharts might be inserting mysterious numbered categories on a chart. ( I say "erroneous" but I'm sure it's something simple)

The JSFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/wilkiejane/sr5dpaft/

The chart that it generates looks like this.....
[image: Erroneous HighCharts]

The code looks like this.....

```
$(function() {
  var data = [{
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Florida",
    "metric": "93.25"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "California",
    "metric": "98.51"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Houston",
    "metric": "98.44"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Twin Cities",
    "metric": "96.56"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Big South",
    "metric": "94.30"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Washington",
    "metric": "98.39"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Heartland",
    "metric": "98.50"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Western NE",
    "metric": "97.06"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Freedom",
    "metric": "97.36"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Boston",
    "metric": "97.40"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Oregon/SW Washington",
    "metric": "98.69"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Keystone",
    "metric": "96.64"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Beltway",
    "metric": "93.39"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Chicago",
    "metric": "98.21"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Mountain West",
    "metric": "98.26"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Florida",
    "metric": "93.25"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "California",
    "metric": "98.51"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Houston",
    "metric": "98.44"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Twin Cities",
    "metric": "96.56"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Big South",
    "metric": "94.30"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Washington",
    "metric": "98.39"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Heartland",
    "metric": "98.50"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Western NE",
    "metric": "97.06"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Freedom",
    "metric": "97.36"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Boston",
    "metric": "97.40"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Oregon/SW Washington",
    "metric": "98.69"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Keystone",
    "metric": "96.64"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Beltway",
    "metric": "93.39"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Chicago",
    "metric": "98.21"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Mountain West",
    "metric": "98.26"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Florida",
    "metric": "93.25"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "California",
    "metric": "98.51"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Houston",
    "metric": "98.44"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Twin Cities",
    "metric": "96.56"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Big South",
    "metric": "94.30"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Washington",
    "metric": "98.39"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Heartland",
    "metric": "98.50"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Western NE",
    "metric": "97.06"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Freedom",
    "metric": "97.36"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Boston",
    "metric": "97.40"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Oregon/SW Washington",
    "metric": "98.69"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Keystone",
    "metric": "96.64"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Beltway",
    "metric": "93.39"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Chicago",
    "metric": "98.21"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Mountain West",
    "metric": "98.26"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Florida",
    "metric": "93.25"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "California",
    "metric": "98.51"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Houston",
    "metric": "98.44"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Twin Cities",
    "metric": "96.56"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Big South",
    "metric": "94.30"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Washington",
    "metric": "98.39"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Heartland",
    "metric": "98.50"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Western NE",
    "metric": "97.06"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Freedom",
    "metric": "97.36"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Boston",
    "metric": "97.40"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Oregon/SW Washington",
    "metric": "98.69"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Keystone",
    "metric": "96.64"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Beltway",
    "metric": "93.39"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Chicago",
    "metric": "98.21"
}, {
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Mountain West",
    "metric": "98.26"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Beltway",
    "metric": "97.94"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Washington",
    "metric": "98.57"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Oregon/SW Washington",
    "metric": "97.06"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Freedom",
    "metric": "98.72"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Houston",
    "metric": "98.31"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Twin Cities",
    "metric": "98.58"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Keystone",
    "metric": "98.83"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Heartland",
    "metric": "98.65"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Boston",
    "metric": "98.70"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Florida",
    "metric": "98.45"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "California",
    "metric": "98.76"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Big South",
    "metric": "98.24"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Chicago",
    "metric": "98.16"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Western NE",
    "metric": "98.34"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Mountain West",
    "metric": "98.54"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Beltway",
    "metric": "97.94"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Washington",
    "metric": "98.57"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Oregon/SW Washington",
    "metric": "97.06"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Freedom",
    "metric": "98.72"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Houston",
    "metric": "98.31"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Twin Cities",
    "metric": "98.58"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Keystone",
    "metric": "98.83"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Heartland",
    "metric": "98.65"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Boston",
    "metric": "98.70"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Florida",
    "metric": "98.45"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "California",
    "metric": "98.76"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Big South",
    "metric": "98.24"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Chicago",
    "metric": "98.16"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Western NE",
    "metric": "98.34"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Mountain West",
    "metric": "98.54"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Beltway",
    "metric": "97.94"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Washington",
    "metric": "98.57"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Oregon/SW Washington",
    "metric": "97.06"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Freedom",
    "metric": "98.72"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Houston",
    "metric": "98.31"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Twin Cities",
    "metric": "98.58"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Keystone",
    "metric": "98.83"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Heartland",
    "metric": "98.65"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Boston",
    "metric": "98.70"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Florida",
    "metric": "98.45"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "California",
    "metric": "98.76"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Big South",
    "metric": "98.24"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Chicago",
    "metric": "98.16"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Western NE",
    "metric": "98.34"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Mountain West",
    "metric": "98.54"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Beltway",
    "metric": "97.94"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Washington",
    "metric": "98.57"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Oregon/SW Washington",
    "metric": "97.06"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Freedom",
    "metric": "98.72"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Houston",
    "metric": "98.31"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Twin Cities",
    "metric": "98.58"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Keystone",
    "metric": "98.83"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Heartland",
    "metric": "98.65"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Boston",
    "metric": "98.70"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Florida",
    "metric": "98.45"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "California",
    "metric": "98.76"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Big South",
    "metric": "98.24"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Chicago",
    "metric": "98.16"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Western NE",
    "metric": "98.34"
}, {
    "day": "06/02/2016",
    "region": "Mountain West",
    "metric": "98.54"
}]

  var exist, index, options = {
    xAxis: {
      categories: []
    },
    series: []
  }
  Highcharts.each(data, function(p, i) {
    exist = false;
    if (options.xAxis.categories.indexOf(p.day) < 0) {
      options.xAxis.categories.push(p.day)
    }
    Highcharts.each(options.series, function(s, j) {
      if (s.name === p.region) {
        exist = true;
        index = j;
      }
    });
    if (exist) {
      options.series[index].data.push(parseFloat(p.metric))
    } else {
      options.series.push({
        name: p.region,
        data: [parseFloat(p.metric)]
      })
    }
  })
  $('#container').highcharts(options);
});
```

As you can see I am only supposed to have two dates in there 6/1 and 6/2 . Has anyone dealt with this before?

Comment: You're sending more data points than dates, so the chart fills in what's missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate JSON entries will kill you everytime. That simple

Comment: If you want to have every point with the same date, you can add name to your point and use categories: true. Here you can see an example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/sr5dpaft/1/
If you want something else, I think that you can use all the answeres provided to achieve your goal. Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the objects in the array is repeating. Like this

```
{
    "day": "06/01/2016",
    "region": "Florida",
    "metric": "93.25"
}
```

See this object is repeating many times.